# Exception while using google-cloud library to execute BigQuery queries

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run a truncate statement from a spark code(from dataproc cluster) using the google-cloud-bigquery library .

1)This is the code

```
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.{BigQueryException, BigQueryOptions, QueryJobConfiguration}
import com.google.cloud.http.BaseHttpServiceException
object BigQueryClient {

  def truncateBigQueryTable(tableName: String): Unit = {
    val bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance.getService
    try {
      val truncQuery = s"TRUNCATE TABLE  `$tableName`"
      val truncQueryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(truncQuery).build
      bigquery.query(truncQueryConfig)
    }
    catch {
      case e: BigQueryException =>println("Table truncation failed \n" + e.toString)
    }
  }

}
```

2)In build.gradle , I have added the dependency

```
implementation group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-bigquery', version: '1.133.0'
```

3)In the Spark Job I have added the google-cloud-bigquery jar as a dependency as well.

```
--jars gs://bucket_name/google-cloud-bigquery-1.133.0.jar
```

But when I run the spark job , it fails with the following error:

**`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/http/BaseHttpServiceException`**
My question is what is it that I am missing ? Because I am already adding the jar as an argument in the spark job.

Answer (score 1):

use `--packages com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:1.133.1`. It will make spark download all the transitive dependencies as well

Answer (score 0):

It's running in my case

```
sparkSession
    .conf()
    .set(
        "spark.jars.packages",
        "com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.18.1");
```

Please use the version as per the scala version you have in the cluster.

Comment: The class that is causing the issue is BaseHttpServiceException and its not a part of spark-bigquery-with-dependencies jar but a part of google-cloud-bigquery jar.And even though I have added the jar in the spark submit command , it still throws an exception